# Revert back on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a jquery script that changes DOM on first click. How would I able to revert back on second click?

For Example

```
var left='.lessonNavigation li.expanded.left';
var actLsn='.lessonNavigation li.activeLesson';
var right='.lessonNavigation li.expanded.right';
var leftArrowHTML='<li class="left arrow"><i class="icon icon-arrow-left"></i></li>';
var rightArrowHTML='<li class="right arrow"><i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i></li>';


$('.lessonNavigation').on('click', '.right.arrow', function () {
    $('.arrow,.inactiveRightArrow,.inactiveLeftArrow').remove();
    if ($('li:last-child').hasClass('expanded right')) {

        $(actLsn).attr('class','expanded left');
        // $(left).prev().;
        $(right).attr('class','activeLesson');
        $(actLsn).before(leftArrowHTML);
        $(actLsn).after(rightArrowHTML);
        $('.arrow.right').attr('class','inactiveRightArrow');

    } 
});
```

Comment: Whatever condition you use for the first click, check for the opposite in order to determine the second.

Answer (score 0):

To revert back, you could just have a second event listener for the new class, example:

```
$('.type1').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('.type1');
    $(this).addClass('.type2');
});

$('.type2').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('.type2');
    $(this).addClass('.type1');
});
```

Comment: .toggleClass might be cleaner

Comment: I have injected some HTML in DOM as well
`$(actLsn).before(leftArrowHTML);
$(actLsn).after(rightArrowHTML);`

it needs to be removed on second click as well. I'm not looking for .remove() function. I'm looking for some revert type of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to just use a toggle rather than an add and remove.

This is a simple function I played with a while back:

```
$(function() {
    $('.yell').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("green");
    });
});
```

My purpose was making a slide-out.

[A working example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/j4c8h).